# WPF-MVVM: Adding New Entity

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

In a MVVM LOB application where data is persisted via EF service layer I have the following WPF EmployeeView which displays Employee Data via binding to Employee Model object contained in the EmployeeViewModel (Employee object is populated in controller class and persisted through the same class) :

[image]

here is xaml:

```
{
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="ID:" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
                 Text="{Binding Employee.ID,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="50" />

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="First Name:" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" 
                 Text="{Binding Employee.FirstName,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="150" />

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="Last Name:" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" 
                 Text="{Binding Employee.LastName,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="150" />


        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Text="Department:" />
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Width="150" SelectedValuePath="." 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Employee.Department,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Employee.DepartmentLookup}" DisplayMemberPath="DepartmentName" />

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="6" Text="Birth Date:" />
        <DatePicker Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" 
                    SelectedDate="{Binding Employee.BirthDate,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7" Text="Hire Date:" />
        <DatePicker Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7" 
                    SelectedDate="{Binding Employee.HireDate,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

        <Button  Height="25" Width="50" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="8" Command="{Binding Path=NewEmpCommand}">
                <TextBlock Margin="1">New</TextBlock>
        </Button>

        <Button Margin="150,5,5,5" Height="25" Width="50" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="8" 
                Command="{Binding Path=AddEmpCommand}">
                <TextBlock Margin="1">Add</TextBlock>
        </Button>
}
```

and the ViewModel

```
    public class EmployeeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{


    //NewEmpCommand
    private DelegateCommand _newEmpCommand;
    public DelegateCommand NewEmpCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _newEmpCommand??
                   (_newEmpCommand= new DelegateCommand(NewEmployee));
        }
    }

    //AddEmpCommand
    private DelegateCommand _addEmpCommand;
    public DelegateCommand AddEmpCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _addEmpCommand??
                   (_addEmpCommand= new DelegateCommand(AddEmployee));
        }
    }


    //ctor-------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public EmployeeViewModel ()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
     //
    }

    private void NewEmployee()
    {
        this.Employee = null;
    }


    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void AddEmployee()
    {
      //here I send the Employee Model object to the service layer to be persisted 
    }


    //Binding----------------------------------------------------------------------

    private Employee _employee;
    public Employee Employee        
    {
        get { return _employee; }
        set
        {
            if (_employee!= value)
            {
                _employee= value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Employee");
            }

        }
    }



   //---------------------------------------------------------
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

I omitted the unnecessary details. Now I want to click New button to clear all the controls so I use the statement "`this.Employee = null;`" (correct me if it is not the right way)
Then I want to enter the new value into the controls where (to my understanding) it should be assigned to the Employee model object.

to the questions:

1.is this the right way to clear the controls preparing for entering new data

2.When I enter the new data and try to save it (via sending the Employee Object to an EF Service  layer to save changes the Employee object is null and the process fail. How to fix this problem?

Comment: Just come to mind, how about creating brand new `Employee` object upon button "New" clicked? That will answer both questions. And it is logically correct, click "New" button -> create "New" `Employee`.

Comment: @har07 How the new Employee object will get the data from the controls

Comment: @codemania, please be aware that edits are meant to improve a post and are not just there to give users reputation. I have noticed that you have taken the time to edit a great many posts recently. Please also take the time to *label your edits correctly*... it is *not* acceptable for you to label them all *code should be like*, regardless of what your edit actually involved.

Comment: @Sheridan.. thanks for your suggestion. i'll take care of this things

Comment: @Hussein Automatic? Data-binding will take care of it if you set it up correctly (your code snippet posted looks fine for me). Try it out.

Comment: @har07 I tried it and I think you are right . please add your comment as an answer to mark it as an answer.one last thing if that view add the newly added employee to another datagrid view displayed in the same time how to make the datagrid display the added Employee directly.

Comment: Assuming that you have `ObservableCollection` of `Employee` as items source of datagrid, then you added the newly created `Employee` to the `ObservableCollection`. It is again, will be automatically displayed in datagrid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Converting my comment to answer as requested :**

Simply create a brand new `Employee` object upon button "New" clicked. That will answer both questions:

1. It is a better way (if I can't claim it as *right* way) to clear
   controls preparing for entering new data
2. That can avoid Employee object is null problem when trying to save

And it is logically correct, click "New" button -> create "New" `Employee`.